# $\exists A\in E,\forall\epsilon>0,\exists I_{\epsilon}\in P_f(I),\forall J\in P_f(I),I_{\epsilon}\subset J\Rightarrow ||A-A_J||\le\epsilon$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> Can you explain me the following definition please. I understand what the statement in general means, but I think there are some typos
>
> Let $E$ be a real or complex vector space with norm $||.||$, $I$ be an arbitrary set and denote $P_f(I)$ the set of all finite subsets of $I$. If $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of vectors in $E$, for all finite subsets $J\subset I$ ,we note $A_J:=\sum\limits_{i\in I} a_i$

($\textbf{now,what i dont understand}$)

Then a family $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ in $E$ is summable if

$\exists A\in E,\forall\epsilon>0,\exists I_{\epsilon}\in P_f(I),\forall J\in P_f(I),I_{\epsilon}\subset J\Rightarrow ||A-A_J||\le\epsilon$

> Why $A\in E$, must it not $A\subset E$
>
> Acording to the definiton $I_{\epsilon}$ is the smallest finite set, does it make sense ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a vector $A$ such that for any real positive number $\epsilon$ there is a finite set of indexes $I_{\epsilon}$ such that for any other finite set of indexes $J$ which contains $I_{\epsilon}$ the distance between $A$ and $A_J$ is less than or equal to $\epsilon$.

Comment: I don't see any typo, though I admit it's a bit convoluted.